# Is there a way to avoid exposure of javascript methods on client side?

Tags: javascript, browser

i have a javascript file which contains methods to handle incoming data from different server.since javascript files are loaded on browser, client can view all those javascript methods, variables, etc.. so is there a way to avoid this leak ?

Comment: What sensitive data is contained in these methods that you don’t want leaked?

Comment: mabye you looking for [this](https://jscrambler.com/en/how-it-works). fyi, i just know it recently..

Answer (score 0):

No, javascript is client-sided, and no sensitive information should be displayed there, just like any program, everything can be reverse engineered.

The solution is to make a request to your server with the data, execute the function INSIDE the server and then send the response. Just like google maps do, when you search for a route, you ask google to calculate the route, the path finding algorythm is not downloaded when you access the website.

Sadly, that's the only option you can rely on

Edit: It's not a solution, and it's not 100% safe, but, using an API like Angular or React and then minifying the code might mangle the code enough that it's HARDER to read, but you still risk it being reverse engineered

Comment: If you are interested in code protection do not use minifiers, you could use Jscrambler as Fal said.
It protects your JS files and also offers code locks as client-side defense mechanisms or anti-debugging feature.
Even their starter version that doesn't offer locks or defense seems to do a better job with concealing the code than other tools.